# ES6 typeof throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

ES5 `typeof` is considered safe, as it will **not** throw `ReferenceError` when checked agains a non-declared value. such as

```
console.log(typeof undeclaredVar); // undefined
```

however, when checking for `typeof undeclaredLetConst` in es6 it will throw an error **only** if the value was later on declared with a `let` or `const`. if it was declared with var it will work normally.

```
console.log(typeof undeclaredLetConst);
let undeclaredLetConst = "hello";  // ReferenceError
```

whats happening there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Why it works with `var` declarations

When a JavaScript engine looks through a lexical scope block and finds a variable declaration with `var`, it hoists the declaration to the top of the function (or global scope if no `"use strict"` is present).

Hence the `typeof` will never fail as the variable its checking upon will be hoisted beforehand.

## The Temporal Dead Zone *(TDZ)*

> The *TDZ* is never named explicitly in the ECMAScript specification, but the term is used to describe why let and const declarations are not accessible before their declaration.

### Why it fails with `const` and `let`

When a JavaScript engine looks through a lexical scope block and finds a variable declaration with `let` or `const`, it places the declaration in the *TDZ*. Any attempt to access a variable in the *TDZ* results in a runtime error.

The declaration is removed from the *TDZ* during **runtime** once the flow reaches the declaration itself.

```
console.log(typeof undeclaredLetConst);     // "undefined"

if (1) {
    let undeclaredLetConst = "no errors!";
}
```

`undeclaredLetConst` isn’t in the *TDZ* when `typeof` operation executes because it occurs outside of the block in which `undeclaredLetConst` is declared. That means there is no value binding, and typeof simply returns "undefined".

**Source:** An awesome book by *Nicholas C. Zakas*, Understanding ECMAScript 6.

Comment: The question I want to ask is, the TDZ is okay for simple references, but why do that with `typeof` ?