# Variable scope Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = true;

if (x == true) {
  console.log(typeof(x));
  let x = false;
};

console.log(x);
```

Sorry new to programming and getting this error:
Error: x is not defined.

I am extremely confused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav

Comment: you have x defined outside the `if` statement.... the let might be changing its scope. If what you're trying is just assign a value just due `x = false`

Comment: The error message for Firefox is a bit more usefull here  `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'x' before initialization`

Comment: Have a look at the *The Temporal Dead Zone* [TDZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39427692/8122487)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it, but the two variables you declared are different. Your `var` declaration is one of them, and the `let` declaration is different. You've confused yourself by naming them with the same variable.

The `let x` exists strictly within the `if` block. This `let x` is the only `x` that can exist in that block now and you've tried to use that `x` before you declared it when you attempt a `console.log`.

You can get away with using variables before you declare them with `var`, but let and const won't let you.

Also, I highly recommend you don't mix `var` and `let` in your code. You have to really understand what's going on if you do.

```
var x = true; // first x variable

if (x == true){ // first x variable
  console.log(typeof(x)); // second x variable, used before declaration
  let x = false; // second x variable created in `if` block
};

console.log(x); // first x variable
```

edit:
Your follow up question is still 2 different variables. The only thing you've done is coerced the code to make it look EVEN MORE like the same variable.

```
var x = true; // first x
if (x == true) { // first x
    let x = false; // second x
    console.log(x); // second x, false
};
console.log(x) // first x, true
```

Comment: It might be a bit clearer if you actually name the variables differently in the code. E.g. `x1` and `x2`. It will become quite clear what is happening then.

Comment: @vlaz I agree 100%, but I don't think that's the origin of confusion. I'm pretty sure OP thinks that the `x` is the same variable in every line of sample code provided

Comment: Indeed, I agree. I just think that if you post an example with the variables named differently it's a bit easier to grasp at a glance.

Comment: @Andrew I guess so, so I am confusing myself, I started with a global variable, and then went into the if block and tried changing the value on a local scope. I guess the mistake I was making was I was treating it as a single variable, when in fact there are two variables. I guess it is safe to conclude you cannot change the scope of a variable once its created? Once again everyone, Thanks!

Comment: @Abdulrehman Yes this is correct. But as you can see, scope can be overwritten when you switch around declarations using the same variable name. This is why a lot of linters don't let you use "shadow variables". Shadow variables are variables that you declare with the same name in a function. Also, don't mix `let` and `var` in your code. Use one or the other or you're going to confuse the hell out of yourself unless you know exactly what you're doing

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, here I'll bug just a bit more, when you said: "But as you can see, scope can be overwritten when you switch around declarations using the same variable name. " Isn't this not true, because when you switch the declaration statement here:               
    var x = true;

    if (x == true) {
    let x = false;
    console.log(x); // false
    };
You are still creating a new variable and then accessing, not changing the scope of the original.

Comment: @Abdulrehman Updated

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little tricky to explain, but I'll try;

```js
var x = true;

if (x == true) {
  console.log(typeof(x)); // <-- Error: x is not defined.
  let x = false;
};

console.log(x); // true
```

The last line is actually fine because you defined `x` up top.

What's happening inside the `if` statement is that JavaScript looks ahead and sees that you've declared `x` (with `let` or `const`) somewhere in that scope, but it hasn't yet reached that line.

So merely having a `let` or `const` somewhere further down in the same scope is causing that variable to not be defined.

If you move it up a line, everything is fine:

```js
var x = true;

if (x == true) {
  let x = false;
  console.log(x); // false
};

console.log(x); // true
```

And if you don't redeclare `x`, it's also fine:

```js
var x = true;

if (x == true) {
  let y = false; // different variable name (won't "shadow" the `x` from above)
  console.log(x,y); // true false
};

console.log(x); // true
```

`var` behaves differently:

```js
if (true) {
  console.log(y); // undefined
  var y = false; // `var` is less strict. The declaration of `y` is hoisted to the top of the scope, but it's not assigned until this line
  console.log(y); // false
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The part of explanation that everyone is missing is that declarations are [hoisted](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp%20hoisted), which means that the declaration is brought to the beginning.

This is especially true with `var`. For `let` things are a little bit different and the term hoisting is not the most accurate. But it is useful to understand what is going on.

When executed, your code will look something like this (not exactly but gives the idea)

```
var x = true;

if (x == true) {
  let x // hoisted at top of scope, for let scope is this if block
  console.log(typeof(x));
  x = false;
};

console.log(x);
```

Now everything should make sense: `typeof(x)` refers to the `x` declared with `let` but not yet initialized.

To be clearer this is the reason why the `x` inside of `typeof` refers to the `x` declared in the row below and not the one at the beginning: because the declaration of the existence of x inside that block is brough to the beginning of such block

Comment: This is not true. `let` is not hoisted. That's why the error is thrown

Comment: `let` declaration is hoisted, its initialization is not, that is why the error is thrown: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6

Comment: @Francesco No. It's hoisted with `var` but not `let` -- otherwise it would have printed "undefined". Try **running** your code, it gives a different result than OP's.

Comment: I'm aware of this (I promise), but in layman's terms, saying "hoisting doesn't exist in `let` is the easiest way to convey the concept because there is no delineation between hoisting and initialization when using `var`. Initialization vs hoisting is a textbook explanation and for the sake of a newcomer, saying "hoisting doesn't occur" is the best way to convey the concept. @mpen Francesco is technically correct.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear... it is "hoisted" in the sense that merely having ` let` further down will cause an error. So we actually having three things going on, but I'm not certain of the correct terminology. There's "declaration" (x is a thing that exists, always hoisted), "initialization" (set x to undefined, hoisted with var but not let/const), and "assignment" (set x to false, never hoisted)

Comment: I agree on the fact that hoisting is probably not the most accurate term, and the executed code is _something like_ what I wrote. But I think that the confusion in the OP is due to the lack of knowledge of hoisting concept which applies partially in this case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried to make the answer more precise and understandable